# Why authenticate() return None for inactive users?

Tags: django, authentication, django-custom-user

I have `CustomUser` like following :

```
        class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
            email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
            username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
            is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
            is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
            ...
```

which is `active` `default=False`
After user registration automatically  handle `UserLogin` def which is :

```
        def UserLogin(request):
            if request.POST:
                username = request.POST['username']
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=request.POST['password'])
                print('user :', user)  # which is print None if user inactive 
                if user is not None:
                    print('is user active:', user.is_active)   # should print True or False  
                    if user.is_active:
                        login(request, user)
                        ... 
                    else:  # handle user inactive
                        ...
                else:  # for None user 
                   ...
```

I still trying understanding why `authenticate` return `None` for inactive users ?

After searching I found smilier issue [user.is_authenticated always returns False for inactive users on template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993714/user-is-authenticated-always-returns-false-for-inactive-users-on-template)
 But didn't find an answer for my situation

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly, note that Django comes with a [login view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) and [authentication form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm) which display suitable error messages when inactive users try to log in. If you use them, then you probably don't have to change the behaviour for `authenticate()`.

Since Django 1.10, the default `ModelBackend` authentication backend does not allow users with `is_active = False` to log in.

If you want to allow inactive users to log in, then you can use the `AllowAllUsersModelBackend` backend.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend']
```

See the [`is_active`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active) docs for more info,

Comment: Glad it works, but changing `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` might be unnecessary. Using the built in login view and form is probably a better approach.