# How to display some message if the user account is not active during login?

Tags: python, django

Here I am trying to display some messages if the username and password is correct but if the `is_active` field is false but it is not displaying the message with this code.It is displaying me the `else` part even if the username and password are correct of that inactive user.How can I do it ?

I think after making `is_active` field to false it sets the User to `None`

views.py

```
form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            remember_me = form.cleaned_data['remember_me']
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            if user and not user.is_active:
                messages.info(request,'Sorry your account is deactivated now.')
                return redirect('/login/')

            elif user and user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                if not remember_me:
                    request.session.set_expiry(0)
                else:
                    request.session.set_expiry(settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE)
             else:
                 messages.error(request, 'Invalid login credentials. Try Again.')
                 return redirect('/login/')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49553511/why-authenticate-return-none-for-inactive-users) helped me.

I added this in my settings.py file and it worked.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend']
```